# Loop through serialized data

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to use jqueryui sortable to reorder columns in a table by dragging and dropping, however I don't know how to even return the data to the POST action, let alone loop through it.

I am generating my `<ul>` like so:

```
<ul id="sort">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li id="id_@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</li>
    }
</ul>
```

This is the sortable js code:

```
$('#sort').sortable({
            update: function () {
                var ids = $('#sort').sortable('serialize');
                var url = "/admin/cms/ReorderPages";
                $.post(url, ids, function (data) {
                    $("#msg").html(data);
                });
                console.log(ids);
            }
        });
```

And my POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public string ReorderPages(string ids)
        {
            return ids;
        }
```

Upon dragging and dropping I get the following console logged:

```
id[]=1&id[]=4&id[]=2&id[]=3&id[]=14
```

So that part works, but how do I get that into my POST action and loop through it to get the ids?

Comment: hint: `id` != `ids` and `string` != `array`.

Comment: thanks friends, got it!